# How can I add an int (minutes) to LocalDateTime.now()?

Tags: java, int, addition

I want to modify `LocalDateTime.now()` by adding a certain amount of minutes to it. How do I do that?

Comment: Do you mean to say the system's date and time?

Comment: `LocalDateTime fiveMinutesLater = LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(5)` ? Assuming that LocalDateTime is from the Joda framework.

Comment: I belive that is what I was looking for, Henrik. Thank you!

Comment: I'm quite new to programming and especially java. I did see `plusMinutes` but I had no idea it had to be appended to `LocalDateTime.now()` like that.

Comment: @Pshemo He missed it because it does not exist in Java 8 (https://i.imgur.com/DYwLU30.png)

Comment: @IanBoyd Your example is about `LocalDate` which doesn't include *time* of the day, which is why there is no methods for minutes. OP example is about `LocalDateTime` which had [`plusMinutes(long minutes)` in Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#plusMinutes-long-).

Answer (score 106, accepted):

If you are using java 8 then you can still use the same syntax

```
LocalDateTime fiveMinutesLater = LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(5)
```

Comment: Definitely worked for me. Below is my example:    {String currentDate = LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(5).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"));}